# AES Password based encryption

Tags: aes, encryption-symmetric

I am trying to encrypt my password and keep it in a properties file to decrypt it later in my code. My question is, if we encrypt the password using a secret key and use the same secret key to decrypt it later, isnt it still a security thread as the secretKey is hardcoded at both the encryption application and the decryption application.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping keys embedded in an executable provides little to no protection. If the application is a web application on Windows, there are built-in mechanism to secure secrets such as connection strings.

If it is a client server application within a Windows domain, you can use Windows Authentication.

A complete answer will depend on the context of your question.